# Generate PDF from view to send email attaching the PDF file without saving it into disk Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, email, attachment

I am working on sending email function. Firstly, I want to generate .pdf file from my view. Then I want to attach the generated .pdf file by email without saving it into disk. I use below in my controller:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('getpdf', $data);
Mail::to($to_email)->send(new Mysendmail($post_title, $full_name))
->attachData($pdf->output(), "newfilename.pdf");
```

And I get this error: "Call to a member function attachData() on null"

If I use below without attachment, it works well:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('getpdf', $data);
Mail::to($to_email)->send(new Mysendmail($post_title, $full_name));
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need to attach it to the message, not to the mailer.

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('getpdf', $data);
$message = new Mysendmail($post_title, $full_name);
$message->attachData($pdf->output(), "newfilename.pdf");
Mail::to($to_email)->send($message);
```

Comment: That works great! I have another question- how about I want to do the same thing with file upload (.pdf / .doc)? I mean I don't want to save it into disk but attach it directly.

Comment: I think it is pretty much the same way. attachData($file, 'filename')

Comment: I tried this. attachData($request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(), 'filename')  . As the result, it does send attachement but the attached file can't be open- it is corrupted.

Comment: getClientOriginalExtension gives the extension of the file. Try attachData($request->file('file')->getRealPath(), 'filename');

Comment: My working way is $message->attach($request->file('file')->getRealPath(), array('as' => 'filename', 'mime' => $request->file('file')->getMimeType()));

Answer (score 1):

Just use 'mime' => 'application/pdf', at last of your code. Simple!

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('getpdf', $data); 
Mail::to($to_email)->send(new Mysendmail($post_title, $full_name)) 
->attachData($pdf->output(), "newfilename.pdf"), [ 
'mime' => 'application/pdf', 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'mime' => 'application/pdf', at last of your code. Simple!

`
   

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('getpdf', $data);
      Mail::to($to_email)->send(new Mysendmail($post_title, $full_name))
      ->attachData($pdf->output(), "newfilename.pdf"), [
                        'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                    ]);
    `